# iOS in background continue to upload the data

Tags: ios

I create a timer,through open the GPS keep App alive every 3 mintues,and then upload data.Then I found the timer was suspended,but the app was alive.Please someone tell me?

Comment: tell you what? what you don't know?

Comment: can you availe some code that we can check

Comment: dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0));
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer,^(){
        NSLog(@"date=====%@",[NSDate date]);
    });
    dispatch_resume(timer);

Comment: I found the timer suspended for 1 mintue almost.

Comment: for example
2017/11/21 21:50:41:729  date===2017-11-21 13:50:41 +0000
2017/11/21 21:50:42:752  date===2017-11-21 13:50:42 +0000
2017/11/21 21:51:45:721  date===2017-11-21 13:51:45 +0000
2017/11/21 21:51:46:697  date===2017-11-21 13:51:46 +0000

Answer (score -1):

You need to become acquainted with Background Execution, here are few useful links I've found so far:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/01/13/ios9-background-execution/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started